# Running curl on current buffer inside vim

Tags: curl, vim, vim-plugin

How do i run the curl command on either a marked url in visual mode or on the complete buffer.

For example:

Lets says that you have 1 row in the current buffer with:

```
https://example.com/
```

I have tried:

```
[1]    :r !curl -kv
[2]    :r !curl -kv .
```

returns:

```
[1]     curl: no URL specified!
        curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

[2]     curl: (6) Could not resolve host: .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of . you can insert the buffer using `Crtl-R "`.

(And other register can be inserted similarly. You can list the registers before like `:registers` if you want.)